# What is a database provider?

Tags: database, vapor

I have limited exposure to databases. I am learning about web frameworks (Vapor) and all the tutorials add a database provider of some sort to their projects. Can you please explain to me what a database provide is and its role in a web app?

The tutorial I am following is integrating this provider: [postgresql-provider](https://github.com/vapor/postgresql-provider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the term used a couple ways, but in a general sense, a database provider is a framework, driver, or object library which enables your web application to send SQL statements to a database and receive data.

Sometimes the provider is a class library in your web app's language (here are a few for the [.NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx), for example).  In other cases it may be a type of [ODBC driver](https://www.progress.com/faqs/datadirect-odbc-faqs/what-is-an-odbc-driver) which you can access using the ODBC standard.

Answer (score 0):

A database provider is said to be written with packages like PL/SQL or any other database package.
http://www.thessaloniki.gr/portalHelp2/ohw?topic=provwhat_htm&locale=en#DBP